# Converting dynamic website to app using phonegap

Tags: sqlite, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I already have dynamic responsive website with html5,JavaScript and php as backend.The client wants to convert it to an app since he wants offline capabilities. I am totally new to this. Really confused as to how to go about it. We have managed to write sqlite queries for loading the master data. But still unsure as to how all things fall into place.Do we have to include jquery mobile as well.please guide.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things to keep in mind. I'll address the easiest one first - no, you do not need to use jQuery Mobile. jQuery Mobile gives you a nice UI, and a SPA-like framework for your app, but it isn't *required* per se. You can use something else like Ionic for example.

As for the conversion, at a high level, this is what needs to happen.

Imagine your current PHP site has 2 pages. The home page is a list of people. You click on a person and you go to a detail page. You have 2 php pages. The first simply does a SQL query to get people and the second does a SQL query to get one person based on the query param.

In your PhoneGap app, your code is all on the user's device, which means no PHP. Your home page needs to get people, so it has to call an API on your application server. You can use PHP to do the SQL as it does now, but instead of displaying it as a simple HTML list, it outputs it as JSON.

On the PhoneGap side, you can call this via JavaScript and then render the results.

The same goes for the detail view - you would need an API on your server side to return info about the person.

I hope this helps. I also have a full blog entry on this, with demo, here: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/05/05/converting-a-dynamic-web-site-to-a-phonegap-application

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I had already seen your page on the conversion. I our case we want the app to work offline hence we are calling server to load initial data and then saving the data to the phone. However we are unsure if this will coz overload to the phone and how will the integration happen with phonegap. Should we change the ui completely? So many such doubts due to lack of base in this area.

Comment: You can store data on the mobile device rather easy - see the Cordova docs for a review. "Overload" - well, obviously you can't store gigs of data, but you can definitely store a reasonable amount of information locally.